# Magento 2 Cron job can't get finalPrice for configurable product

Tags: magento2.2.2, crontab, cronjobs

I have the following in my cron folder and also I have the following the Controller folder which is exact same code and it get the price when I load in the url but it refuse to get price in cron folder.

I can get the name just fine but no price

[image]

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class GenerateXml
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_stockItemRepository;
    protected $_fileSystem;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_imageHelper;
    protected $_stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        $this->_fileSystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $mediaProductUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';
        $placeholderImageUrl = $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
        $content = '';
        $fileName = 'test';
        $productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
                $productCstock = $this->getStockItem($product->getId());
                $prices = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
                $content .= '<item>' . PHP_EOL;
                $content .= '<price>' . $prices . '</price>' . PHP_EOL;
                $content .= '<title>' . $product->getName() . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
                $content .= '</item>' . PHP_EOL;
                $configChild = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
                foreach ($configChild as $child) {
                    $productStock = $this->getStockItem($product->getId());
                    $content .= '<item>' . PHP_EOL;
                    $content .= '<price>' . $prices . '</price>' . PHP_EOL;
                    $content .= '<title>' . $product->getName() . '</title>' . PHP_EOL;
                    $content .= '</item>' . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        }
        $feed = $this->createHeader() . $content . $this->createFooter();
        $media = $this->_fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $media->writeFile("customFeed/" . $fileName . ".xml", $feed);

        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockRegistry->getStockStatus($productId);
    }

    public function createHeader()
    {
        $header = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' . PHP_EOL;
        $header .= '<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' . PHP_EOL;
        $header .= '<xs:element name="item">' . PHP_EOL;
        return $header;
    }

    public function createFooter()
    {
        $footer = '</xs:element>' . PHP_EOL;
        $footer .= '</xs:schema>' . PHP_EOL;
        return $footer;
    }

}
```

I've also tried different method such as `getFinalPrice()` but no luck in cron. It only works in controller.

Anyone know what I could be missing in cron get price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run cron functionality with store emulation.

```
protected $emulation;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation
)
{
    $this->emulation = $emulation;
}

public function execute()
{
    $_store = 1;
    $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($_store, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

    // your logic here

    $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
}
```

As cronjob does not have store settled, so you need to run your code by above way.

Comment: you'r star That works as treat. Just need to correct my answer actually it  was just the configurable product that I couldn't get final price and also the product url  was returning the non-friendly url now with emulation in place everything is returning correctly.

Comment: Thats great, have a good day !!!!